# Filtrar por más de un campo con filter pipe

Tags: angular

me preguntaba si es posible filtrar por más de un campo tipo que yo escriba en un input y me este filtrando a la vez por varios campos de la base de datos o pueda buscar por distintos campos, de ser así como puedo hacerlo ya que solo tengo un ngModel

```
<ng-select [searchable] [virtualScroll] name="terapeutasfilter" [(ngModel)]='filterTerapeuta1' *ngIf="tipo == 1">
    <ng-option value=''>Todos los terapeutas1</ng-option>
    <ng-option value='{{fpersonal1.id}}' *ngFor="let fpersonal1 of personal">{{fpersonal1.nombre}} {{fpersonal1.apellidos}}</ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

Os comento lo que quiero hacer ya que estoy.

Tengo 1 tabla que se llama paciente y cada paciente tiene de 1 a 3 terapeutas asignados tipo

```
Terapeuta1 = 3
Terapeuta2 = 5
Terapeuta3 = 6
```

Estas con las ID's del terapeuta en cuestión en su tabla, entonces lo que yo quiero hacer es decir muéstrame todos los pacientes de este terapeuta

Filter

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'; import { HistorialComponent } from '../components/historial/historial.component';    

    @Pipe({   name: 'historialfilterper' }) export class HistorialperfilterPipe implements PipeTransform {   constructor(public historialComp:HistorialComponent){

      }   transform(items:any, filterHistoria:string, filterTerapeuta1: string) {
        if (items && items.length){
            return items.filter(item =>{
                if (filterTerapeuta1 && item.terapeuta1.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterTerapeuta1.toLowerCase())
    === -1){
                    return false;
                }
                if (filterHistoria && item.historia.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterHistoria.toLowerCase()) ===
    -1){
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
           })
        }
        else{
            return items;
        }

    }

    }
```

Mi código HTML donde hago el for y filtro el pipe

```
<div class="card-body-pacientes" *ngIf="tipo == 1">
    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50" minBufferPx="200" maxBufferPx="400" class="viewport"> 
        <div *cdkVirtualFor="let fpacientes of pacientes | historialfilterper:filterHistoria:filterTerapeuta1" class="visitas mt-1" (click)="loadcita(true);getPaciente(fpacientes.historia);getHistorial(fpacientes.historia);modificarda(true);activate(false);modificarci(false);modificate(false)">
            <span>{{fpacientes.historia}} - {{fpacientes.nombre}} {{fpacientes.apellidos}}</span>
        </div>
    </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>  
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres a algo como `*ngIf="(tipo == 1) || (tipo == 3)"`?

Comment: Hola Oscar, quiero sacar los pacientes asociados a 1 terapeuta no se a que te refieres con eso

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir tu implementación de `filterTerapeuta1`?

Comment: Hola OscarGarcía listo, ya está agregado

Comment: No veo el uso del pipe en tu código HTML (como un `algo | Historialperfilter`). ¿Podrías decirnos qué es `tipo` y algunos valores de referencia de `personal` y `filterTerapeuta1` para poder reproducir tu problema?

Comment: Ya lo agregué al post

Comment: Tengo parcialmente reproducido tu código aquí: [https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-pg3j8](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-pg3j8). [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95617/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-miguel-angel-martin).